# Copy Paste VBA Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that takes parts of one sheet and paste values on the next. I know using select isn't ideal. But i Don't know how to do it other wise. In the past i have got a out of range error if i was not selecting the sheet before hand. In the macro i have y defined earlier but I am getting an

> 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

```
y = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count
Sheets("Bucket12").Select
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Range(Cells(y, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Range(Cells(y, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Range(Cells(y, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: where are you getting this error?  Are you sure there are worksheets (in the same workbook) called `Bucket12` and `upload`?

Comment: yes i am getting an error on the first line with y in it

Comment: @UserX I've fixed your error message for you, but please take note that error messages are very explicit, so it's important that you write (and spell) exactly what they're telling you - otherwise, it's hard to know what your issue is.

Comment: We also need to see where you give a value to `y`.

Comment: I added it. However, I dont think y is the issue. I think it has to do with selecting sheets and pasting destination

Comment: @ashleedawg y is the variable, title states its an issue copying and pasting to a new sheet. The code is what I tried. Everything is in there

Comment: @ashleedawg it is all in there k thanks

Comment: Be very careful of references like Cells(y, 3) where you don't specify the parent sheet name. It is implicitly referencing the activesheet. Much of what I can see could be re-written to avoid .Select and use With statements that hold the parent sheet and inside of the With use .Cells or .Range.

Comment: The second range in the copy is using whichever sheet is active. If you have `Bucket12` selected then `Cells(y,3)` is using that and not `upload`. The two ranges are on different sheets so will throw an error.

Comment: @QHarr Yes i am trying to avoid select. Is it possible to do that when moving back and forth and copying from one sheet, pasting to another, and having to do that multiple times in sucession? I am trying to find examples of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `Range()` expects two arguments - `Cell1` and `Cell2` - you're only giving it one argument, which is throwing error 1004.

Instead, just use `.Cells()`:

```
y = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count
Sheets("Bucket12").Select
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Cells(y, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Cells(y, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Bucket12").Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("upload").Cells(y, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Better yet, let's avoid `Select`, `Copy` and `Paste` altogether:

```
y = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bucket12")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("upload")

lastrow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(y, 2), sht2.Cells(lastrow + y - 2, 2)).Value = _
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 3), sht1.Cells(lastrow, 3)).Value

lastrow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(y, 3), sht2.Cells(lastrow + y - 2, 3)).Value = _
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 5), sht1.Cells(lastrow, 5)).Value

lastrow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(y, 5), sht2.Cells(lastrow + y - 2, 5)).Value = _
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 7), sht1.Cells(lastrow, 7)).Value
```

As another note - it's better to use `xlUp` than `xlDown` when determining your lastrow for data entry.

Comment: Thanks. @dwirony Why is it better? So it doesn't go all the way down to the bottom of the sheet by accident?

Comment: @UserX Not only that, but blanks in your column will halt the search, giving you a false representation.